# I am setting up nginx docker container as reverse proxy to php-fpm. Is it even possible?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, arm

I am working on my raspbberry pi (arm architecture) and I am using docker to run containers on a very lightweight OS (HyperiotOS). I have successfully set the nginx + php-fpm container that nginx config serves php file if the volume is mounted with code on both containers.

Now my problem is: I am trying to set the nginx pretty much as reverse proxy, meaning I don't want the nginx to access any code on drive I would like to forward all requests into php container and display results. I tried proxy_pass to it, but it did not work. Is there a way to do that ? Example of code below.

My docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: arm32v7/nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./code:/code # this is what I want to get rid off
    networks:
      - webserver
  php:
    image: arm32v7/php:7.3-fpm
    expose:
      - "9000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
    networks:
      - webserver
networks:
  webserver:
    driver: bridge
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name raspberry.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /dev/null =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Now inside the /code folder, I have index.php with php info.
This configuration works well and after accessing raspberry.local:8080 I can see php info page.

However, in order to access it, I have that /code mounted in nginx container.

```
- ./code:/code # this is what I want to get rid off
```

Now I want to eliminate that so I can put the nginx as balancer somewhere else without the need to access code. I would like to proxy the requests straight to php container. I tried proxy_pass http://php:9000 but that broke the thing. What is the best way to "detach" the nginx from the code and just act as a standalone proxy? There are several reasons why to eliminate that if possible, one is production type build. I cannot share the folder it needs to be baked in. I don't want two containers carrying the code. I could just throw in apache into php container and proxy nginx inside if that would be the case and eliminate the fpm.