# laravel in php-fpm as reverse proxy in docker: don't want to put 2 sets of files in both containers

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I think I am asking a question that is 90% similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508251/i-am-setting-up-nginx-docker-container-as-reverse-proxy-to-php-fpm-is-it-even-p), but I did not see any response, so I put it here again.

Most of the Docker + Nginx + PHP-fpm tutorial found on the web are mounting the same code directory to both Nginx and PHP-fpm.

But I don't want to.  I just want to keep PHP-fpm as a reverse proxy that response to Nginx request.

So the architecture is:

```
Traffic <-> Nginx (as docker container) <-> php-fpm (as docker container)
```

- Nginx as a proxy server, no code.
- PHP-fpm contains all REST-API code (Laravel in this case), response to Nginx request.

I can use `fastcgi_pass` to send/direct traffic from Nginx to PHP, but since Nginx did not have code, it will immediately return `404 Not Found`.

Are there anyone who can successfully do that?  If so, can the config be shared?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Put empty index.php into nginx container (can be done in his dockerfile). Tricky but working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all people who comes from search engine, or searching for a solution.  I wrote a gist for that.

https://gist.github.com/alucard001/4fc56ba20b58d9b1e69b5e3dce276f6a

I know that it violates the rules here but I hope that can still be accepted, as I put a lot of effort to make it work.

It use Nginx + PHP (Swoole) instead of PHP-FPM.

Thank you.

Update: This Gist is for Laravel.  If you want to use it on another platform/project (e.g. Wordpress), please change your `Dockerfile` or `Dockerfile_base` accordingly.

You may need to change the image from `php:latest` to `php:8-fpm` in order to run non-Laravel PHP program.